# IF else statement not working properly in vba code

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

Hi please see the following code im trying to print volume and the package size based on volume using if else in vba. but my code only works fine for the volume part but when it comes to the size it is printing the first condition throughout i.e small not printing the rest. can you help me to see where am i going wrong.
the table has the following coulmns with values in multiple rows:
package name, date, length, width, height, volume, size.

works fine for volume but not size[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blyEm.png)

Sub FillDown()

```
Dim strFormulas(1 To 2) As Variant

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    strFormulas(1) = "=PRODUCT(C2:E2)"

    If Range("F2").Value > 0 And Range("F2").Value < 1000000 Then
        strFormulas(2) = "Small"

    ElseIf Range("F2").Value > 1000000 And Range("F2").Value < 9000000 Then
        strFormulas(2) = "Medium"

    ElseIf Range("F2").Value > 9000000 Then
        strFormulas(2) = "Large"

    End If
    .Range("F2:G2").Formula = strFormulas
    .Range("F2:G44").FillDown
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: If `G2` is the text "Small" and you `FillDown`, `G2:G44` will all be "Small". Make `strFormulas(2)` an actual formula based on `F2`, not text. Your if/else works just fine.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you need to account for sizes that are exactly 1000000 or 9000000. Those don't hit any of your conditions - you need either `<=` or `>=` depending on what group they should fall into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You don't want the same *small/medium/large* values from row 2 in all of G2:G44.

```
Sub smlFillDown()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("F2:F44").Formula = "=PRODUCT(C2:E2)"
        .Range("G2:G44").Formula = "=lookup(f2, {0, 1000000, 9000000 }, {""small"", ""medium"", ""large""})"
    End With

end sub
```